# How to re-order data in memory to optimize cache access?

Tags: c#, performance, caching

I want to shuffle a big dataset (of type `List<Record>`), then iterate over it many times. Typically, shuffling a list only shuffles the references, not the data. My algorithm's performance suffers tremendously (3x) because of frequent cache missing. I can do a deep copy of the shuffled data to make it cache friendly. However, that would double the memory usage.

Is there a more memory-efficient way to shuffle or re-order data so that the shuffled data is cache friendly?

Comment: Show your code please - I have removed Java tag also since it seems to have no relevance to your question

Comment: If your `Record` type is not a struct then you won't have any control over where the data is held in memory even if you *DO* make a deep-copy. The only way is to use a struct, I think.

Comment: Each record is rather large (~1KB), not efficient to use struct (in general). Plus, I cannot change the record type.

@Sayse: it is relevant because this question applies to Java as well. They are both managed languages, which means that I cannot easily change the memory structure as in C++.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1:

Make `Record` a `struct` so the `List<Record>` holds contiguous data in memory.

Then either sort it directly, or (if the records are large) instead of sorting the list directly, make an array of indices (initially just `{0, 1, ..., n - 1}`) and then sort the *indices* by making the comparator compare the elements they refer to. Finally if you need the sorted array you can copy the elements in the shuffled order by looking at the indices.
Note that this *may* be more cache-unfriendly than directly sorting the structs, but at least it'll be a single pass through the data, so it is more likely to be faster, depending on the struct size. You can't really avoid it if the struct is large, so if you're not sure whether `Record` is large, you'll have to try both approaches and see whether sorting the records directly is more efficient.

If you can't change the type, then your only solution is to somehow make them contiguous in memory. The only realistic way of doing that is to perform an initial garbage collection, then *allocate* them in order, and keep your fingers crossed hoping that the runtime will allocate them contiguously. I can't think of any other way that could work if you can't make it a `struct`.
If you think another garbage collection run in the middle might mess up the order, you can try making a second array of `GCHandle` with *pinned* references to these objects. I don't recommend this, but it might be your only solution at that point.

#### Option 2:

Are you **really** using the *entire* record for sorting? That's unlikely. If not, then just extract the portion of each record that is relevant, sort those, and then re-shuffle the original data.

Comment: Good solution. One caveat is that if `Record` is rather large and there's a lot of them, the array used by the `List` *could* go over 2GB in size and therefore fail - perhaps unlikely, but something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

It is better for you not to touch the List. Instead you create an accessor method for you list. First you create an array of n elements in a random order e.g something like `var arr = [2, 5, .., n-1, 0];`

Then you create an access method:

```
Record get(List<Record> list, int i) {
    return list[arr[i]];
}
```

By doing so the list remains untouched, but you get a random Record at every index.

Edit: to create a random order array:

```
int[] arr = new int[n];

// Fill the array with values 1 to n;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    arr[i] = i + 1;

// Switch pairs of values for unbiased uniform random distribution:
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++) {
    int j = rnd.Next(i, arr.Length);
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: This won't help with the OP's problem of cache misses though.